# the program runs less than 2 sec

Tags: c++

I got this code from MSDN to change the Text to speech and I did all the sitting which were in the tutorial the code works without errors but when I run the code the code run for less than 2 second and then come back to the main code without read the code. my question here is what is the problem exactly?

this is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <sapi.h>
#include <initguid.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;
    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SpVoice), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(SpVoice), (void **)&pVoice);
    if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
    {
        hr = pVoice->Speak(L"Hello world", 0, NULL);
        hr = pVoice->Speak(L"This sounds normal <pitch middle = '-10'/> but the pitch drops half way through", SPF_IS_XML, NULL );
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Try setting breakpoints and generally debugging. There’s no indication if `!SUCCEEDED(hr)` in that code, for example.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I tried with breakpoints, still isn't working. and I changed SUCCEEDED(hr) to if( !SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) and still nothing

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `CoCreateInstance()` is wrong.  You are passing the CLSID of the `SpVoice` CoClass where the IID of the `ISpVoice` interface is expected instead (so it should be failing with an `E_NOINTERFACE` error).

Try this instead:

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
```

Alternatively:

```
CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SpVoice), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pVoice));
```

Comment: when I used this call CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
I get these error: Error 3 error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals and this error Error 1 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CLSID_SpVoice, and this error also Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_ISpVoice. So I change the calling to this call CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(SpVoice), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(SpVoice), (void **)&pVoice);

Comment: To resolve the external symbols, make sure you are linking to `sapilib.lib`.  If you use `__uuidof()` instead, then the second `__uuidof()` must be `__uuidof(ISpVoice)` instead of `__uuidof(SpVoice)` (`IID_PPV_ARGS()` would handle that for you).  `SpVoice` is the CoClass, `ISpVoice` is the interface.